# Magento 2: Display specific categories to specific usergroups

Tags: magento2, category-view

Sorry guys this might be bit silly question but I am new in Magento.

I am trying to display specific categories according to specific Usergroups:

For example: I have usergroups

> 1. "customergroup1",
> 2. "customergroup2"
> 3. "customergroup3"

And I have Categories

> 1. "category1",
>
>    2. "category2",
>    3. "category3",
>    4. "category4"

etc

Now I want if customer belongs to "customergroup1" he can only see "category1" and "category2"

And if customer is from "customergroup2" he can only veiw "category2" and "category3" etc

My first priority is to do this without extension.